# Xamarin.Forms (droid build) MultiDex option causes app to crash

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Our Xamarin.Forms project has expanded to include libraries with a method count >= 64k so we have had to enable MultiDex.
Since enabling it, the droid build is crashing immediately upon deployment to my android emulator.

I've searched the web and the only solution I have found is to uninstall all of the xamarin.android and mono runtimes on the device, which I have done. This did not solve it.

My device log shows the following error after the app crashes:

```
01-10 08:38:44.593 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1966 memtrack Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-10 08:38:44.593 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1966 android.os.Debug failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-10 08:38:44.565 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1966 cutils-trace Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5ca27074e405277e6c40e6a6588077a84.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cii.patrollive-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.cii.patrollive-1, /system/lib]]
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime ... 11 more
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:507)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime Process: com.cii.patrollive, PID: 1948
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4301)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application md5ca27074e405277e6c40e6a6588077a84.MainApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5ca27074e405277e6c40e6a6588077a84.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cii.patrollive-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.cii.patrollive-1, /system/lib]]
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:502)
01-10 08:38:39.201 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1948 AndroidRuntime at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
01-10 08:38:38.917 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1938 memtrack Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-10 08:38:38.917 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1938 android.os.Debug failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-10 08:38:38.845 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1938 cutils-trace Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-10 08:38:38.541 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1926 cutils-trace Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-10 08:38:38.469 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1926 memtrack Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-10 08:38:38.469 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1926 android.os.Debug failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-10 08:38:34.757 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1896 android.os.Debug failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-10 08:38:34.757 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1896 memtrack Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-10 08:38:34.729 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1896 cutils-trace Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-10 08:38:34.445 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1880 android.os.Debug failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-10 08:38:34.445 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1880 memtrack Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-10 08:38:34.421 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1880 cutils-trace Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-10 08:38:34.145 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1866 android.os.Debug failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-10 08:38:34.145 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1866 memtrack Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-10 08:38:34.113 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone Error 1866 cutils-trace Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your application is crashing is potentially two-fold:

1. You do not have a ACW name for your `MainApplication` and thus one is generated for you.

> Android Callable Wrappers will be based on the MD5SUM of the assembly-qualified name of the type being exported.

In the example you posted, we see `md5ca27074e405277e6c40e6a6588077a84.MainApplication`. Thus when we lookup the `MainApplication` on the `dexlist`, we expect that exact name. Thus changing the name to something more ideal like a package name helps out here.

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_5/xamarin.android_5.1/#Android_Callable_Wrapper_Naming

2. The `MainApplication` class was not put on the main `classes.dex` list and thus at startup, it tries to find the class and cannot find it because it's in the secondary `classes2.dex` file. The secondary `.dex` file is not loaded until `Multidex` is initialized. You can read up more about Multidex here:

http://www.jon-douglas.com/2016/09/05/xamarin-android-multidex/

http://www.jon-douglas.com/2016/09/23/xamarin-android-multidex-keep/

Comment: Despite the fact that adding a Name to the MainApplication class solved the issue, today the issue has re-emerged and the Name is still defined. What is the solution for the second fix? How can I add the missing class to classes.dex as you described?

Comment: See my second blog post regarding using a `MultidexMainDexList`.

Comment: I've read that but it is not clear to me what needs to be done. `Create a new Text file multidex.keep in your main application root.` does this mean the root of the android project? Or the solution root that contains each platform project? and it also instructs `Set the Build Action to MultiDexMainDexList` I don't know what is meant by set the build action  ?

Comment: It will be in the root of your Android project. The build action would be `MultiDexMainDexList`, and you would manually include everything you want on the main dex list. Ideally you can take what's generated by default in your `classes.dex` and then add the additional classes to it.

Comment: Jon I don't know what "The build action would be `MultiDexMainDexList` I don't know what a build action is. Are you talking about enabling multidex?Is this the name of the build parameter? Also, the generated `classes.dex`(in output bin/Debug) already had the class that the error message reports is missing. Would that indicate that this is not the correct fix?

Comment: James, A `build action` is set on the `Properties` of a file. They are typically custom actions for how that file should be treated. I would highly recommend you post the contents of your `classes.dex` file to your question so I can see what's going on here.

Comment: And by posting contents, I would recommend just attaching the whole file so it can be used in `classyshark` or equiv.

Comment: Jon it is working now despite making none of these changes. This is frustrating as I would prefer to know exactly what fixed it. Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a solution. 
Specifying a Name attribute on the MainActivity in the droid project solved it. (I had not specified a name before this). (Required a clean & rebuild as well)

I don't know why you need to specify the activity Name after adding the MultiDex option, I'm guessing it is a Xamarin bug.

```
[Activity(    ...    , Name= "com.cii.patrolliveapp",    ...    ]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    ...
}
```

Edit:
There is also a second issue which was indicated to me by Jon in the other answer. It is a bug on the android sdk on windows where the first dex class list is empty.

The fix is to open your `android-sdk\build-tools\<version>\mainDexClasses.bat` file (where version is the highest one you have installed, which is the default) and change this:

```
if DEFINED output goto redirect  
call "%java_exe%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%" com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder "%disableKeepAnnotated%" "%tmpJar%" "%params%"  
goto afterClassReferenceListBuilder  
:redirect
call "%java_exe%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%" com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder "%disableKeepAnnotated%" "%tmpJar%" "%params%" 1>"%output%"  
:afterClassReferenceListBuilder
```

to this:

```
SET params=%params:'=%  
if DEFINED output goto redirect  
call "%java_exe%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%" com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder %disableKeepAnnotated% "%tmpJar%" %params%  
goto afterClassReferenceListBuilder  
:redirect
call "%java_exe%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%" com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder %disableKeepAnnotated% "%tmpJar%" %params% 1>"%output%"  
:afterClassReferenceListBuilder
```